# How to store the salaries & IDs of employees in multi-dimensional arrays using for loop and updating them through another function ( C )

Tags: c, arrays, function, loops

So the question should be rather simple (not to me tho for some reason).
i need to give some employees some IDs and give those IDs their own salary.and allow said employee to be stored **IF** their salary is above a set point. so far I've been able to (brokenly) implement this (*i apologize if it seems like i'm talking a lot it's just that i can't seem to explain my problem that easily*)

OLD code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void Employee_Data(int number_of_employees,
    float Data[3][number_of_employees],float salary){
    int i ;
    for(i = 0 ;i < number_of_employees;i++){
        printf("Employee %d\n\n",i+1);
        printf("enter the salary of employee %d:",i+1);
        scanf("%f",&salary);
        printf("\n");
        }
    }

int main() {
    printf("Enter the number of employees: ");
    int number_of_employees = 0;
    scanf("%d",&number_of_employees);
    float Data[3][number_of_employees];
    float salary;
    Employee_Data(number_of_employees,Data,salary);
  return 0;
}
```

what i need is a way to set an ID that the user inputs in the above function
and another function to print out the employees and their IDs if they have a salary over a number that the user also inputs and lastly (most likely the hardest) a function to give a raise to employees which are picked by their IDs and said raise is to be percentage wise of their current salary

Once again i apologize if it's too long and too confusing i have a bit of problems trying to get my point to be understood hopefully it is though.

NEW CODE

```
#include <stdio.h>
float employee_ID(int number_of_employees,int ID[number_of_employees]){
    for (int i = 0; i<1;i++){
        scanf("%d",&ID[i]);
    }
return *ID;} 

float Salary_of_employees(int number_of_employees,int salary[number_of_employees]){
    for(int i = 0; i<1;i++){
        scanf("%d",&salary[i]);
    }
return *salary;}

void printing(int number_of_employees,int *salary[number_of_employees], int *ID[number_of_employees]){
    for(int k = 0; k<number_of_employees;k++){
        printf("Employee %d 's ID is %d and their salary is %d\n",k+1,*ID[number_of_employees],*salary[number_of_employees]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int number_of_employees;
    int ID[number_of_employees];
    int salary[number_of_employees];
    printf("Please input the number of employees you need : ");
    number_of_employees = 0;
    scanf("%d",&number_of_employees);
    int i;
    for (int i = 0; i<number_of_employees;i++){
        printf("please input the ID for employee %d\n",i+1);
        employee_ID(number_of_employees,&ID[number_of_employees]);
        printf("please input the salary of employee %d\n",i+1);
        Salary_of_employees(number_of_employees,&salary[number_of_employees]);
    }
    printf("if you want to see the IDs and the salaries of the employees please write 1\n if you want to ");
    int choice;
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    if (choice == 1){
        printing(number_of_employees,salary,ID);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Currently my problem with this is that i've got 2 warnings at the calling of the printing function (salary and ID are the warnings for some reason can't get them to be fixed)

And my other problem is that the storing only takes the last inputted number given by the user. for example if i give an ID of 321 and a salary of 543 the output of the printing function would be employee number(thank god the counter works)'s ID is 543 and the salary is 543 (TO EACH EMPLOYEE)

Edit1: So basically when i run the code it asks me to input the number of employees. (so far so good) when i insert the number it starts with employee number 1 and asks me to input the salary. upon inputting the salary it just gives me 2 new lines and stops basically what i need is that each time it'd -instead of saying employee 1- it'd first ask me to set the employee ID first and then say "Employee -insert ID-'s salary: "and then asks me to insert the salary of said employee. and then the same for each employee that i set . + the other functions

Edit2: Updated the code by removing the for loop that seemingly crashed the program and updated the title + (i think) explained the stuff that i need better

Edit 3: after messing around **and legit deciding to restart the code** i began experiencing some uhhh trouble with the storing for some reason. and decided to add the new code and keep the old one as well

Comment: If you can narrow it down to specific problems we can help with those. For example, what output you are getting, what you expected. Perhaps you could also show a session - what you entered, what you expected to happen when you did.

Comment: Done thank you @DannyStaple

Comment: Can you give more information on what the inner loop with J is intended for?

Comment: @DannyStaple i think that i don't need the inner J loop let me update some stuff rq

Comment: Done please check now if it's better explained

Comment: Getting there. Why are there 3 floats per employee? Also in the main loop, it should probably still be setting something in the array.

Comment: Getting there. Why are there 3 floats per employee? Also in the main loop, it should probably still be setting something in the array.

Comment: Should i remove the 3 from the array and instead put salary?

Comment: It looks like you have. The new code looks a bit confusing. Starting with the top function `Salary_of_employees`, am I right to assume the intent of this function is: given the number of employees, and a list to store the salary in, store the salary for each employee in the list.
If so: 
* what is it returning (caller doesn't appear to use return)
* Why is it looping only once?

Answer (score 0):

You have an inner and outer loop over the number of employees. Not only will this behave strangely, but Its likely that if you enter more than 3 employees the code will crash. The J loop doesn't look right.

Comment: Do you think i should add a new variable then? if so what will it's use be? a counter?